# determine if checkbox is selected angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Wanting to determine if a checkbox has been selected in the latest version of angular using an if statement.

**My code:**

```
<mat-menu #wj="matMenu">
   <section><mat-checkbox (id)='1' (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Cool Kids</mat-checkbox></section>
</mat-menu>

<div class="float-right">
 <mat-action-row>                           
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click) = "generateLink()" >Generate Link</button>
</mat-action-row>
```

**AND IN component.ts:**

```
generateLink() {
    <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('1')
    if(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('1')){
        console.log('y');
    }      
}
```

The idea is that once the submit button is pressed, the `generateLink()` method will evaluate to see all of the checkboxes checked by ID. If there is a better method to do this then please share. Essentially, there are 15 checkboxes, and I need to collect all of their values in an array at the end when a submit button is pressed.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular 2+? I removed AngularJS because it appears as though you are using Angular 2+, and `angularjs` is the incorrect tag for that framework.

Comment: angular 2, my apologies

Comment: You're missing the whole point of angular: you shouldn't get values from the DOM. The single point of truth is the model, and the view is bound to the model. Read the guides on forms, and bind your input to your model. Then you can just know, from the model, whether the checkbox is checked or not. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know that mat-checkbox generates an inner id for the **MatCheckbox** object.

Secondly, I agree that you should manage your elements state via Forms.

However, if you still want to track whether certain checkboxes are checked or not, you could track it.

Link: [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzfaym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Simply, I am using a service to emit each selected checkbox as a MatCheckbox object.

Then, I iterate over the MatCheckbox array when the Button is clicked, and each iteration the **checked** object will be evaluated and print its id to the console just for demo purpose.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be to use the Reactive forms instead. That way, you would have more control over your form.

```
// In your typescript
  myForm: FormGroup;
  mycheckboxControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.mycheckboxControl = new FormControl();
    this.mycheckboxControl
      .valueChanges.subscribe((res) => console.log(res));

    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
     checkobx: this.mycheckboxControl
    });
  }
// In your HTML
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" [formControl]="mycheckboxControl">
```

[You can play more with form here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odizvj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)